# How to create site-to-site VPN from CentOS Server to Windows Server

Tags: centos, vpn, openvpn, site-to-site-vpn, sstp

For a small business: at one site is windows 2012 server, (with ssl certificate), already running as a SSTP VPN Server.

At a remote site, is a live-to-public CentOS webserver running CFS.

Requirement: To establish a permanent and reliable VPN tunnel between the two servers.

What would be a recommended best practice here?

e.g Is it feasible (and reliable) to use a linux SSTP client on the CentOS Server for a permanent site-to-site VPN?

Or would it be better to establish a new OpenVPN connection on both servers etc?

Comment: I would probably use ipsec  via libreswan/strongswan/openswan on the centos end.

Comment: Thanks, thats the kind of pointer I am looking for. Question: any particular reason you would choose that over, for example, OpenVPN?